# Position sticky for table body column with dropdown

Tags: html, css

Ladies and gentelmen,
I have the following problem: I want to have 1st and 2nd columns of my table to be sticky. For that, I am applying "sticky" position to them. One of the columns has a dropdown and the issue is that dropdown content is not visible because it is covered by lower "sticky" columns.
I assume that the problem is that z-index: auto works differently for "sticky" and for "relative/fixed" positions.
It would be extremely helpful if you could provide me solution of how to resolve my problem.

```
z-index: auto
```

CodePen is here: http://jsfiddle.net/pqkj7v5r/1/
Please note, that CodePen is just an example and for my real task I can not really use any specific values.

Expected dropdown content to be above lower rows but the actual result is that it is partially covered by them.

Comment: Please update you question with the code (just a link is not ok).

Comment: just u want to make the dropdown visible am right? I have one solution but it is not based on z-index. whether it is ok for u ?

Comment: @AmareshSM yes, I need dropdown visible but first 2 columns (one of which includes the dropdown) being sticky

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do this :

```
.dropdown-menu {
    position: relative;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bscyzv9u/